# "Nosy Neighbor" and the CFQ scheduler

Tags: performance, kvm-virtualization, io, linux-kernel, cloud-storage

I'm trying to understand how does using CFQ affects the "Nosy Neighbor" problem.
I'll ask it a bit naively, can a "Nosy Neighbor" even exist when using CFQ? Isn't that CFQ should make sure all processes(VMs) get fair slices of storage time? If so, how can one VM I/O interfere with another's VM I/O when CFQ is being used?

Environment is CentOS6.5+OpenStack+KVM+Ceph

Comment: And which operating system? I'd probably be [using the `deadline` scheduler](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/linuxonibm/liaat/liaatbpcfq.htm) instead of CFQ regardless, though.

Comment: OS is Linux, can CFQ be found elsewhere?

Comment: How "use deadline" answers "how does using CFQ affects the "Nosy Neighbor" problem"?

Comment: Because the standard practice for configuring KVM atop modern Linux is to use the Deadline scheduler. By "which OS", I meant "which distribution/kernel/release", because the schedulers have evolved over time.

Comment: Distribution is CentOS 6.5. See here, I/O scheduler selection doesn't make much difference for Ceph: http://ceph.com/community/ceph-bobtail-performance-io-scheduler-comparison/